# Problems with style sheet not displaying wName

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is the xml code

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="autotxt.xsl" ?>
<delivery>
<wName>Reston</wName>
<wContact>John McAdams</wContact>
<orderDate>8/15/2005</orderDate>
<recvDate>8/21/2005</recvDate>
<recvBy>David Hanson</recvBy>
<sCost>385</sCost>
<manifest>
  <item itemID="CM204">
     <itemName>Camshaft (Box 20)</itemName>
     <itemQty>10</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>289.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="CR201">
     <itemName>Carburetor (Box 25)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>159.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="CRK310">
     <itemName>Crankshaft (Box 10)</itemName>
     <itemQty>3</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>109.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="DS503">
     <itemName>Distributor (Box 15)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>125.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="EC501">
     <itemName>Engine Computer (Box 1)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>414.59</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="OP460">
     <itemName>Oil Pump (Box 20)</itemName>
     <itemQty>3</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>214.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="SP300">
     <itemName>Standard Spark Plugs (Box 100)</itemName>
     <itemQty>10</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>114.45</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="SP310">
     <itemName>Delux Spark Plugs (Box 100)</itemName>
     <itemQty>10</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>139.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="TB261">
     <itemName>Timing Belt (Box 40)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>94.90</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="TR301">
     <itemName>Transmission (Box 1)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>310.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="BA105">
     <itemName>Standard Batteries (Box 12)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>495.40</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="BA205">
     <itemName>Security Batteries (Box 4)</itemName>
     <itemQty>3</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>289.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="BA115">
     <itemName>Delux Batteries (Box 12)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>525.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="SF305">
     <itemName>Standard Air Filters (Box 16)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>148.25</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="FI372">
     <itemName>Fuel Injection Kits (Box 1)</itemName>
     <itemQty>15</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>129.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="BRK681">
     <itemName>Brake Line Kit (Box 1)</itemName>
     <itemQty>25</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>29.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="CF401">
     <itemName>Cooling Fans (Box 20)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>34.41</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="ALT561">
     <itemName>Chrome-plated Alternators (Box 5)</itemName>
     <itemQty>3</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>105.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="ALT610">
     <itemName>Alternator Case Kit (Box 1)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>69.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="CC310">
     <itemName>Catalytic Converters (Box 5)</itemName>
     <itemQty>3</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>121.59</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="CC315">
     <itemName>Universal Catalytic Converters (Box 5)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>68.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
 </manifest>
 </delivery>
```

Here is the XSL

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">       
 <xsl:output method="html"   version="4.0" /> 
 <xsl:template match="/"> 
 <html>     
 <head>       
 <title>Election Night Results</title>       
 <link href="autotxt.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />     </head>     
 <body>         
 <ul>             
 <xsl:for-each select="delivery/manifest/item">             
 <li> 
 <xsl:value-of select="itemName" />             
 </li>             
 </xsl:for-each>         
 </ul>
 <xsl:for-each select="delivery/wName">             
 <ul>              
 <li>
 <xsl:value-of select="wName" />             
 </li>             
 </xsl:for-each>         
 </ul>

 </body> 
 </html> 
 </xsl:template> 
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

My problem is why does it not display the wName?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation of the problem and for a natural and easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for-each` changes the XPath scope, so it's looking for wName inside each manifest/item (which is why selecting `itemName` works). You can either go back up the tree, by changing the select from "wName" to "../../wName", or alternatively define a variable for the document root at the top of the stylesheet (i.e. outside the for-each):

```
<xsl:variable name="doc" select="/"/>
```

Then inside the for each you can do

```
<xsl:value-of select="$doc/delivery/wName"/>
```

Comment: you've edited the question now so my answer is no longer valid (there was only one for-each in your original version). As Dimitre points out you should now change the `value-of select` to a "." in the second `for-each`, or alternatively change the `for-each select` to just `delivery`.

Answer (score 1):

**In your code**:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="delivery/wName">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="wName" />
            </li>
        </ul>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

You want to output the string value of the `wName` child of `delivery/wName`. However no `wName` element has a `wName` child.

**Solution**: Just output the string value of the already current `wName`:

**Replace**:

```
   <xsl:value-of select="wName" />
```

**with**

```
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
```